# Replace characters from a string with it's position

Tags: java, string

I am having difficulty in the following, replacing certain characters from the string

There will be two inputs, first will be character and second will be string 
then I need to replace all those characters from the string with it's position
for example ,

the input and output of my program are  as follows which is absolutely correct as per the requirement

Input : i this is Ignite 
( Here "i" is the first input and "this is Ignite" is the second input

Output : th2s 5s 8gn11te

Input : i this is ignite and i am pratik

Output :  th2s 5s 8gn11te and 20 am prat30k

The replacement should not be case-sensitive.
I had written the following program but it's having some bugs, Bugs in the sense that I am actually doing some project online and the automated sytem is not accepting the program because of some logical error.The automated system does some test cases with different inputs and check the output ( not exceptions or invalid inputs)  can someone help me identify it ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class rplc
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String str,temp="";
    char ch, ch2;
    int arr[]=new int[100];
    int len,i,x=0;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ch=input.next().charAt(0);
    str=input.nextLine();

    str=str.replaceAll("^\\s+","");

    ch2=ch;
    if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
      ch2=Character.toLowerCase(ch);
    else if(Character.isLowerCase(ch))
      ch2=Character.toUpperCase(ch);
    len=str.length();
    temp=str;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
      if(str.charAt(i)==(int)ch || str.charAt(i)==(int)ch2)
      {
        arr[x]=i;
        x=x+1;
      }
    }
    x=0;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
      if(str.charAt(i)==(int)ch || str.charAt(i)==(int)ch2)
      {
        temp=str.substring(0,i);
        temp=temp+(arr[x]);
        temp=temp+str.substring(i+1,len);
        str=temp;
        len=temp.length();
        x=x+1;
      }
    }
    System.out.print(temp);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you clearly add what is your input (how many inputs) and what should be the output?

Comment: Please be more specific in terms of `it's having some bugs`

Comment: There will be two inputs, first will be character and second will be string

Comment: The output of your current code is: "0 th4s 7s 10gn13te and 21 am prat30k" What wrong with this?

Comment: @User404 no, did you run the program ? there will not be a 0 at the starting , kindly compile and run the program. I had also updated the question with more detail

Comment: I did and that is the result I get (using Netbeans and JDeveloper IDE).

Comment: @User404 I am using eclipse and cmd(javac) and i am getting the following output on this input 

 Input : i this is Ignite 
Output : th2s 5s 8gn11te
this is correct but the automated system is not accepting because of some logical error, what logical error can you see ? Please help

Comment: Use "System.out.println" instead of "System.out.print". You might have missed the 0 by mistake

Comment: @User404 thanks for your help, but no there should not be any 0 at the starting because that "i" at starting is the character that needs to be replaced with the second input(String) that follows .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I liked the problem so I made my own answer. apologies for the dirty looking code. :)

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    String firstInput=input.nextLine().charAt(0) + "";
    //ensure its lower case
    firstInput=firstInput.toLowerCase();
    String secondInput=input.nextLine();
    //ensure char in secondInput is lower cased too.
    secondInput=secondInput.replaceAll(firstInput.toUpperCase(),firstInput);

    String[] splitted=secondInput.split(firstInput);

    String output="";
    int current=0;
    for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
        String s=splitted[i];
        current=current+ s.length();
        if(i==splitted.length-1){
            output=output+s;
        }else{
            output=output+s;
            output=output+ current;
            current++;
        }
    }
    //edited part, as split doesn't split if firstinput is the last character of the string
    if(secondInput.endsWith(firstInput)){
        output=output+secondInput.length();
    }


    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: your program is accepted, but it passed 4 test cases out of 5, can you please recheck the code there is only some logical error left

Comment: When I enter the input as  
i
this is Ignite and this is hellicopteri

the output should be  th2s 5s 8gn11te and th21s 24s hell31copter38
but the output that is coming is th2s 5s 8gn11te and th21s 24s hell31copter 

can you please llook into this

Comment: @Eugene can you send me a test cases that it doesn't work please?

Comment: When I enter the input as i this is Ignite and this is hellicopteri the output should be th2s 5s 8gn11te and th21s 24s hell31copter38 but the output that is coming is th2s 5s 8gn11te and th21s 24s hell31copter can you please look into this ... please note that it's missing the last character there is i at the end and it's ignoring it..

ENter the input as i this is Ignite and this is hellicopteri

Comment: @Eugene ahh yeah i had forgot the problem with using split. I've edidted my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it. But still there is some  minor logical problem in the code and this is why it's not passing the 5th test case of the automated program.  Your code passes 4 test cases out of 5 .  I'm sorry but the test case is not known :(

Comment: @Eugene yep I think I found the problem,  unfortunately my approach won't work(using split), use **Janar** answer. its  a much neater answer

Comment: can you explain the problem ?  and the janar's solution is not passing even 1 test case even though it's correct .

Comment: @Eugene change input.next()  in the second line into input.nextLine()

Comment: there is no input.next() in your program

Comment: @Eugene also replace the the third line into : **String str = input.nextLine().replaceAll((""+ch).toUpperCase(),(""+ch).toLowerCase());**

Comment: @Eugene i meant from Janar answer

Comment: thank you very much for your help.  I am submitting the program with 4test cases passed out of 5 with 93% correctness . thank you ..god bless u.

Comment: @Eugene well, Janar answer should give you 100% . just change the two lines I've mentioned and it'll work. I cannot use his code in my answer, its just rude

Comment: @Eugene http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77199/a if you couldn't figure it out, I'll be happy to send you the code in the chatroom

Comment: ..woow.. i followed ur edits on Jalan's answer and i got 100% .. wow .. god bless you my friend  ... .

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your code should work. Just in case I tried writing a simpler program:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
char ch = Character.toLowerCase(input.next().charAt(0));
String str = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
input.close();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < str .length(); i++) {
  if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
    buf.append(i);
  }
  else {
    buf.append(str.charAt(i));
  }
}
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

And the output seems to be same.
Perhaps your function should return the value instead of printing it?

Comment: cool answer, but you may want to change input.next() to input.nextLine() instead.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. If I understood correctly the input will only be one line, for example "i this is ignite and i am pratik" where "i" is the char and "this is ignite and i am pratik" is the string part.

Comment: yeah true, it'll work if input is assumed to be a one liner " i this is Ignite". but if input is two liner "i" then "this is Ignite" it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I understand that there will be only 1 input from the user.
The following input:

> i this is ignite and i am pratik

Where the first 'i' is the charcter which needs to be replaced in 'this is ignite and i am pratik'.

Modify following:

```
str=input.nextLine();
str=str.replaceAll("^\\s+","");
```

to

```
str = input.nextLine();
str = str.substring(1);
str = str.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this,

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Line = s.nextLine();
    String ch = Line.substring(0,Line.indexOf(" ")).trim();
    Line = Line.substring(Line.indexOf(" ")).trim();
    String[] x= Line.split(ch);
    String y="";
    for(String t:x){
        y=y.equals("")?t:y+y.length()+t;
    }


    System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some code cleaning but the most important steps were to use a list of dynamic size instead of a fixed size array and a while-loop with dynamic termination instead of a for-loop. This is because the length of the output String will change (increase) when there a characters to be replaced at positions >9 and thus in your code the execution can stop in the middle of the result string and there are characters not being replaced. 
There is even a special case, when the replaced character is a number itself. To avoid problems there I added this line

```
i = i + Integer.toString(list.get(pos)).length()-1;
```

in order to step over newly added number characters in the output String.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class rplc
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
    String str=input.nextLine().trim();
    int len=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
      if(str.charAt(i)==Character.toLowerCase(ch) || str.charAt(i)==Character.toUpperCase(ch))
      {
        list.add(i);
      }
    }
    int pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<str.length())
    {
      if(str.charAt(i)==Character.toLowerCase(ch) || str.charAt(i)==Character.toUpperCase(ch))
      {
        String start = str.substring(0,i)+Integer.toString(list.get(pos));
        String end = i<=str.length() ? str.substring(i+1) : "";
        i = i + Integer.toString(list.get(pos)).length()-1;
        pos++;
        str = start.concat(end);
      }
      i++;
    }
    System.out.print(str);
  }
}
```

I can't see any special bugs. Could be that I lost sight of something. This is my first answer here and English is not my mother tongue, so please excuse any formal errors.